# android path like header example

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, header

Hi I am trying to figure out how to make an expandable header that stretches when the user pulls the listview down. An example of this is path, when the user views their profile page, they are able to pull down the listview and the header or image at the top of the page stretched to expand. I have done research into this and cant find an example of how to do this. Could some one help please.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Basically what I am trying to do is get the following result:

[image]

So as you can see from the image above we have the path page, and the image at the to of the listview (in the header section) is partly shown. We then drag the listview down to get the next result:

[image]

As you can see the image has expanded on the listview drag, I am trying to replicate this.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you are exactly looking for. HAve a look at this page, you might find a suitable ui widget there: http://www.androidviews.net/ .Maybe this ui widget fits you need:http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/slide-expandable-listview/ You should provide some screenshot / ui mockup to express what you want to have in your app.

Comment: Just made an edit to the question