# How to implement pull to reveal list view header in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-listview, pull-to-refresh

I'm looking for a way to expand list view header when the list is overscrolled.
Very similar to pull to refresh design but I need this expanded panel to remain visible until I explicitly close it (via some button or action).
It could be a list view header or some other View above the list view which is hidden.
I've failed to find any ready-to-use libraries, I've failed with customizing pull to refresh library by adding a custom animation layout and it also does not work (look good) with SlidingUpPanel because the content of dragable panel when located at top is shown inverted (bottom views displayed first, top views are off the screen)

Please advise hot to approach this task, thanks !

Comment: Have a look at [CollapsingToolBarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html) and [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) to get started

Comment: You mean like Twitter like PullToRefresh?
In that case, this library may help you. But this is no longer being maintained...
https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

Comment: Or you mean Path like PullToRefresh animation?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827891/android-path-like-header-example

Comment: I'm sorry for late response, I was playing around with CollapsingTollBarLayout, yeap this is what I was looking for !